# Django tests pass individually but fail when running together

Tags: django, unit-testing

I have a number of tests that all pass if I just run the file individually in Pycharm.
But if run them as using the DiscoverRunner some of them fail.

I know it must have something to do with the tests setup, so I am looking for input on how to debug this.

Things I already tried based on other stackoverflow answers:

- Make sure all the testscases are django.test.TestCase. Most test load data from fixtures in the class definition.
- Make sure to call the super method where I define the tearDown method.

I had two tests files that used `mail.outbox` when run together. But if I put them together in a package inside the test folder they suddenly passed.

Any idea what could be causing this? Any tips on how to debug this?

Comment: Provide more details about tests.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this. I seem to be facing a similar situation.

Comment: @ReioSantos No nothing that was ever concrete.